# If a $k$-algebra is finitely generated, then does $k$ also have to be a finitely generated field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then does $k$ also have to be a finitely generated field?

Motivation: Let $A$ be generated by $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, and $k$ be generated by $\{k_1,k_2,k_3,\dots\}$. Then the element $k_1k_2k_3\dots a_1\in A$ is not generated by a finite number of elements.

I suppose the case becomes even clearer when $A$ is a unital $k$-algebra. Then the set of generators of $A$ becomes $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n,k_1,k_2,\dots\}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you write «$k_1k_2k_3\cdots a_1$» you have in mind an infinite product?

Comment: In any case, if you are given a set $S$ which generates a ring/algebra/group/vectorspace $X$ then **every** element of $X$ is "generated by a finite number of elements of $S$».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez- yes. All the infinite generators.

Comment: Well, a product of infinitely many elements simply does not make any sense.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something elementary here, but what in the world does $\,A\,$ being or not a f.g. $\,k-$ algebra has to do with $\,k\,$ being a f.g. field...whatever that means outside the realm of finite fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple counter example:

Be $A=\{0\}$ the trivial algebra over $K$: $A$ clearly is finitely generated (it contains just one element!), even if $K$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, $\Bbb{C}$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb{C}$-algebra but not a finitely generated field (since finitely generated fields are countable).